# POST 405 Not Allowed with Particular XMLHttpRequest and ASP

Tags: html, xml, post, iis-8

I am working on a JavaScript application, where I want to read data from an XML file and post them into a HTML file.

My code is producing the following error:

```
Request URL:http://myServer/dirs/dir/scripts/xml_data.xml
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en,en-US;q=0.8,da;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:13
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:myServer
Origin:http://myServer
Referer:http://myServer/dirs/dir/inWork.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
node:xnode-24
Response Headersview source
Allow:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:5309
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 12 Feb 2015 21:06:08 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Based on [this posting](http://sysadmin.circularvale.com/server-config/enabling-post-requests-to-static-eg-html-pages-using-iis-7/) I created a new 'Handler Mapping' and I also adjusted the 'Handler Mapping' for 'StaticFile' to allow the methods: GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE.

The IIS server was restarted but still the error message appears and the only methods allowed are: **GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE**.

So, there is some configuration file or 'Handler Mapping' overriding my settings, or I simply did not consider.

Any suggestions on how to tell the IIS to accept my settings for this XMLHttpRequest?